# Не происходит перенаправление на страницу

Tags: reactjs, jwt

Реализовывал авторизацию и при осуществлении функции выхода из системы столкнулся с проблемой, что необходимо перенаправить пользователя на страницу авторизации. Вот код, который вызывается при нажатии на кнопку LOG OUT в хедере приложения:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();    
const handleLogout = () => {
        //window.location.reload();
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        setIsLoggedOut(true);
        setLoggedIn(false);
        //return <Navigate to="/authorization" />;
        navigate('/authorization');
    }
```

Опробовал несколько способов, даже явно указывал компонент, который должен возвращаться.
В index с роутингом использовал Navigate, чтобы всегда перенаправляло на страницу авторизации, если пользователь не авторизован, что успешно работает. Поэтому собственно и пытался вызывать перезагрузку страницы в функции, но перезагрузка не происходила.
К слову, если выйти, то страница остается открытой и не происходит перенаправление, но после перегрузки страницы перенаправление работает.